# Apollo cache updates list when querying item details

Tags: javascript, reactjs, caching, apollo, apollo-cache-inmemory

I have a problem with Apollo GraphQL:

1. I have a list `categories` and every `category` has a list of `items`.
2. Every `category` has its `id` and every `item` has its `id`.
3. When I pull the list of `categories` with their `items`, I pull only these `items` which are available.
4. When I click an available `item`, I need to pull the `category` details with its `items`, also the unavailable ones.
5. This unfortunately updates the `categories` list with unavailable items.

I don't know how to separate `list` cache from the `details` cache. Unfortunately the objects are always updated.

Answer (score 1):

Your type definitions have an ambiguity that the cache cannot deal with automatically. You can either (a) directly manipulate the cache to get the behavior you want (hard here actually) or (b) define a new field called `availableItems` under `categories` that only has available items.